# postgres, go-gorm - can't preload data

Tags: postgresql, go, preload, go-gorm

I am trying to preload some data when querying for a row on my postgresql with gorm

I have the following types defined in go with a `belongs to` association:

```
type MyObject struct {
    ID            uint      `grom:"column:id" json:"id"`
    Name          string    `gorm:"column:name" json:"name"`
    OwnerID       uint      `gorm:"column:owner_id" json:"owner_id"`
    Owner         Owner     `json:"owner"`
    ...
}

type Owner struct {
    ID         uint            `gorm:"column:id" json:"id"`
    Name       string          `gorm:"column:name" json:"name"`
    Config     json.RawMessage `gorm:"column:config" sql:"type:json" json:"config"`
    Components []uint8         `gorm:"column:components;type:integer[]" json:"components"`
}
```

and the tables in the postgres db with a row as follows

```
my_schema.my_object

id  | name      | owner_id  | ...
----|-----------|-----------|-----
0   | testobj   | 0         | ...


my_schema.owner

id  | name      | config    | components
----|-----------|-----------|-----------
0   | testowner | <jsonb>   | {0,1,2,3}
```

I am running the following query with gorm:

```
object := &models.MyObject{}

result := ls.Table("my_schema.my_object").
    Preload("Owner").
    Where("id = ?", "0").
    First(object)
```

but as a result, in `object` i get the following struct:

```
{"id": 0, "name": "testobj", "owner_id":0, "owner": {"id": 0, "name": "", "config": nil, "components": nil}}
```

I get no errors or warnings of any kind
the foreignkey relation was specified in the database creation sql script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by implementing the `TableName()` method for each of my models as such:

```
type MyObject struct {
    ID            uint      `grom:"column:id" json:"id"`
    OwnerID       uint      `gorm:"column:owner_id" json:"owner_id"`
    Owner         Owner     `json:"owner"`
    ...
}

func (MyObject) TableName() {
    return "my_schema.my_object"
}

type Owner struct {
    ID         uint            `gorm:"column:id" json:"id"`
    ...
}

func (Owner) TableName() {
    return "my_schema.owner"
}
```

Then, I can then use it in a query like the following:

```
myObject := &models.MyObject{}
result := ls.Model(myObject).
    Where("id = ?", id).  //assume any valid value for id
    First(myObject).
    Related(&myObject.Owner)

return myObject, processResult(result)
```

in the end, when making a request for `MyObject` to my server I get all the data of the related `Owner` object in the database:

```
$ curl "http://localhost:8080/api/objetcs/related/1" | jq  // passing 1 as object id value in url params
{
  "id": "1", // taken from UrlParam
  "name": "testobj",
  "owner": {
    "id": "1", // using foreign key owner_id
    "name": "testowner",
    "config": configJson // json object taken from row in my_schema.owner table in the DB
    }
  }
}
```